# Rspec, at once deduce detail failures message

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

When I run rspec tests. I can't see details result of my tests.

I can see

```
FFF.FF.......
```

If my tests executed a many time, me need wait a lot of time to see detail failures message.

Rspec can at once deduce detail failures message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the rspec-instafail gem, there's info and install instructions at GitHub ==> https://github.com/grosser/rspec-instafail